# How to change multiple foreach iteration to single LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

`emailAddresses` is the List of strings. `notificationRequest` is the class has the field `RequestXml` (type is `XDocument`).

`RequestXml` will be like:

```
<root>
    <result>
        <SUBMITTERALIAS>example@domain.com</SUBMITTERALIAS>
    </result>
    <result>
        <SUBMITTERALIAS>example@domain.com</SUBMITTERALIAS>
    </result>
</root>
```

I want to get all the email address in the `SUBMITTERALIAS` to be saved in the string list. So I wrote the following piece of code. I did work and does the job.

```
var emailAddresses = new List<string>();

foreach (var request in notificationRequest)
{
    foreach (var email in request.RequestXml.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS"))
    {
        emailAddresses.Add(email.Value);
    }
}
```

I would like to use single line LINQ code instead of above foreach. Any ideas?

Comment: emailAdresses = (from req in notificationrequest from email in req.RequestXML.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS") select email.value).ToList()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add the address to another list you can flatten the lists with `SelectMany` and use `AddRange`:

```
emailAddresses.AddRange(notificationRequest.SelectMany(request =>
                  request.RequestXml.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS"))
                  .Select(email => email.Value));
```

If you create a complete new list you can simply call it like that:

```
emailAddresses = notificationRequest.SelectMany(request =>
                  request.RequestXml.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS"))
                  .Select(email => email.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var emailAddresses = notificationRequest.
    /// flatten the list of descendats list to email list
    SelectMany(request => request.RequestXml.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS")).
    /// select the value of the email element
    Select(email => email.Value).
    /// convert it to a List
    ToList();
```

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't think it can. `notificationRequest` contains a bunch of `request` objects. The projected `IEnumerable<string>` will need to be flattened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flatten your query so that just it returns a sequence of email addresses:

```
var emailAddresses = 
    from request in notificationRequest
    from email in request.RequestXml.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS")
    select email.Value;
```

And if you actually do need it to be a list:

```
var emailAddressList = emailAddresses.ToList();
```

An OO approach might be to create an `EmailAddresses()` method in `request`:

```
public IEnumerable<string> EmailAddresses()
    => RequestXml.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS").Select(x => x.Value);
```

And change your query to use that:

```
var emailAddresses = notificationRequest.SelectMany(x => x.EmailAddresses());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request.RequestXml.Descendants("SUBMITTERALIAS").ToList().ForEach(x => emailAddresses.Add(x.Value));
```

Comment: This does not reduce the `foreach` nesting. And btw `ForEach` is not linq, but an instance method of `List<T>`.